# Losing Attributes Following Merge in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, modelbuilder, merge

Using ArcMap 10.1, I am working on a project adding polygons to an aerial. The polygons have data associated such as Location, Numerical Value, Street Name, Date, etc...

I use the merge tool as I am combining each individual polygon(100+) to a single shapefile for obvious reasons. But every time I merge, through ModelBuilder, the resulting table does not contain the data needed. I am building an Excel sheet as well with the same data but this seems to be redundant and repetitive unnecessarily. Why does ArcMap rid the table of the column and row data when the merge occurs? I am having to redo all the work numerous times. The first image is how the table looks with the columns: SHEET, STA, DATE completed and filled. The second image is after the merge. Granted, there have been numerous table mods over the course of the week, not associated with this issue.

[image: table2]

[image: Table1]

The goal is to reduce time investment, do the job correctly, but efficiently. Re-filling each field is ridiculous every time. THe alternative is to complete the table in Excel, but that defeats the purpose of having each polygon separate. Also, I could build the table in ArcMap, but then the merge can never take place making them a single polygon as well as the individual poly's.

Comment: Have you checked to see what the field mapping looks like?

Comment: Yes, forgot to include that I have checked the field mapping. Unless I am doing something incorrectly, the fields all align and match. Thoughts on all fields for ALL columns?  Some of the shapefiles do not have the same amount of columns, would this skew the result?

Comment: You say "every time I merge, through ModelBuilder, the resulting table does not contain the data needed".  What happens when you perform the same steps using that tool (and any others involved) one at a time outside of ModelBuilder?  I think it is this sequence of steps that you should show us, taking care to tell us the parameter values you use at each step, and highlighting where the output you observe starts to deviate from that which you expect.